# How important is research on model selection methods in Statistics?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, inference, large-data, linear-dynamical-system

My question is nothing technical. I just wanted your opinion on how important is the model selection problem in the field of Statistics considering the age of big data. Are the current methods such as BIC, EBIC, GIC, etc. not sufficient to decide a good model? Do we need to do more research to find new methods for model selection?

I will be grateful if someone with good experience in this field can provide some insights.

Comment: I'm familiar with BIC, AIC, and CV. All are fairly similar with various pros and cons. The biggest problem isn't finding a technique to select a good model, it's ensuring the model is robust to noise, which is ill defined.

Comment: Additionally not all models can be evaluated with all methods. For example AIC requires a likelihood function, which isn't always available.